# LINQPAD - Read in a csv and store columns into lists

Tags: linq, csv, linqpad

Basically I have a csv of the format of shown below:

The csv has 11 columns with the first five and last five being the exact same.
I want to be able to read in the csv and store all instances of the first and fifth column (Period and Payout) in a list where they have values and do the same with the sixth and eleventh column in another list.

The purpose of this is to compare payouts that match on period between different lists.
Any help whatsoever is appreciated.

```
Period,IndexId,Id,Date,Payout,,Period,IndexId,Id,Date,Payout    
,,,,,,109,75,80010081,03-Sep-2016 05.28.37,239073.74999996735    
,,,,,,202,75,80044661,21-May-2013 06.49.16,3.0170290500000052E7    
,,,,,,8505,75,80035051,28-May-2013 03.32.41,8835437.250000026    
109,128,80010081,03-Sep-2016 05.28.37,239073.749999967,,,,,,    
202,128,80044661,21-May-2013 06.49.16,3.01702905000001E7,,,,,,    
934,128,80041031,13-Oct-2015 20.22.03,1.55494005E7,,,,,,
```

Comment: So, what is your problem here? You can read file lines with `File.ReadLines(fileName)`

Comment: That works even with a csv? If so, then my problem would be how to store the 1st and 5th columns as an object in a list. And then to store the 6th and 11th columns as an object in another list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var values = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
      .Select(x => x.Split(','))
      .Where(x => x[0] != string.Empty)
      .Select(x => new { Period = x[0], Payout = x[4] })
      .ToList();
```

Comment: how can I add the values as integers or doubles if I want to be able to call upon them to add them?